# Segment out visitors that view a certain piece of content more than once?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible?

I have looked at the advanced segment options, done some google searches, and also posted on the Google Analytics Product Forum; but so far I'm not able to find either an answer or a method for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Sequences" option of advanced segments to exclude users based on a series of actions that take place in order, e.g. viewing the same content more than once.

See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en

In your case, you'd likely set up a Sequence as follows:

- Exclude - Users
- Step 1: Page contains (your content)
- Add step
- Step 2: Page contains (your content)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) So, you believe that this will work pan-session, i.e., visit 1 they viewed X piece of content, and then visit 3 they viewed it again?

Comment: As long as it's set up at the User level rather than the Session level, it should work that way.

Comment: Thanks, I've found some Google documentation to back this up so I'm going to assume that this is how it works :)